# C# win8 compatible version of dll

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I've written a library which I now want to make avialable to win8 apps. The problem is that I don't want to copy every code file. I would like to use the same code files in both projects. That means that if I change one codefile, the original dll and the win8 dll will change.

Comment: the answer is in the second tag?

Comment: You don't need an "original" if you can make the whole thing into a portable class library.  That will be compatible with Win8 apps and regular .NET apps.